# Multiple Button Click Events Jquery On

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I bind Multiple Button Click events to the same function as below ?

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn1 #btn2 #btn3", callbackFunction);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use commas to separate the values:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn1, #btn2, #btn3", callbackFunction);
```

Then you can determine which one called you by accessing the `this` object, so the following would alert the id of the element clicked:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn1, #btn2, #btn3", function () { 
     alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

For example, this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SFLDw/1/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. However, you need to separate them with a comma.

$(document).on("click", "#btn1, #btn2, #btn3", callBackFunction);

If possible, it might be wise to assign a class to the buttons and use the class as the seletor. Any button with that class will be bound to the event. This will keep you from having to add additional selectors.